# What is the correct way to write this long sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, parallelism

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> My abilities to work as a part of a team, to lead a group of people,
>   to have the courage to admit my mistakes and learn from them are the
>   best qualities I would bring with me to the program.

There are two specific questions:

- Because I am using *abilities*, I need to use *are* in the end. Is this correct?
- Should "learn from them" be "to learn from them" to preserve parallelism?

Comment: Does the list have three members or four?  That is, are "admit my mistakes" and "learn from them" two entries, or one?

Comment: @Monica: *Them* in *learn from them* makes it clear that this phrase refers to an antecedent (namely *mistakes* in *admit my mistakes*).

Comment: @Danielδ, that's my guess but if so an "and" is missing, which is why I asked.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: It has three in my opinion but yes, as Daniel pointed it out, at least that was the intended meaning.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! This comes under "Please proofread my document" in the FAQ.

Comment: @MetaEd: Hi! Yes if you consider a sentence to be a document (which is probably true for certain areas) :) I had very specific questions at the end of my question but thanks for pointing it out - I will keep in mind to assign better titles from next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, *are* modifies *abilities*, and is correct.  I would not put *to* before *learn* (though it would be grammatically correct) since then it could easily become confused as a fourth "ability".  I would, however, have an *and* before the last "ability" in order to make clear that it is the last of the list:

> My abilities to work as a part of a team, to lead a group of people, **and** to have the courage to admit my mistakes and learn from them are the best qualities I would bring with me to the program.

You could also combine *learn from* and *admit* to render the meaning even clearer:

> My abilities to work as a part of a team, to lead a group of people, and to have the courage to **admit and learn from** my mistakes are the best qualities I would bring with me to the program.

Comment: Wow... Perfect! Thank you very much for your time.